# How can I use a JSONPath expression as a filter inside another JSONPath expression?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I want to select objects from a JSON string by filtering using a JSONPath expression with another expression embedded in the filter.  In other words, I want to filter for a value that is present elsewhere in the JSON data.

For example:

In the following JSON data there is a value in **`$.Item.State.stepId`** (currently "QG2.0"). I need to have a JSONPath expression that selects values based on this value, like this:

```
$..Step[?(@.stepId==$Item.State.stepId)].actionDate
```

But this will not return any results.  If I use the string ("QG2.0") directly like this:

```
$..Step[?(@.stepId=='QG2.0')].actionDate
```

it will return the required data.

What's wrong, or is it not even possible?  My JSON is below:

```
{
    "Item": {
            "Common": {
                    "folio": "PSH-000016020",
                    "setName": "123-XZ200-1",
                    "wfId": "Kat1_002",
                    "wfIssue": "002",
                    "wfIdIssue": "Kat1_002.002"
            },
            "State": {
                    "status": "IN WORK",
                    "stepId": "QG2.0",
                    "stepDescription": "Validation"
            },
            "Participants": {
                    "Participant": [
                            {
                                    "role": "PR",
                                    "roleDescription": "Product Responsible",
                                    "loginName": "marc102",
                                    "email": "mark@abc.de"
                            }, {
                                    "role": "CR",
                                    "roleDescription": "Chapter Responsible",
                                    "loginName": "uli26819",
                                    "email": "uli@abc.de"
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "Steps": {
                    "Step": [
                            {
                                    "stepId": "QG1.0",
                                    "stepTitle": "Preparation",
                                    "actionDate": "2016-06-28T10:28:09",
                                    "actionDueDate": "",
                                    "actionBy_Name": "Marc",
                                    "actionBy_Account": "marc102",
                                    "action": "complete",
                                    "Comment": ""
                            }, {
                                    "stepId": "QG2.0",
                                    "stepTitle": "Check Requirements",
                                    "actionDate": "2016-08-08T14:17:04",
                                    "actionDueDate": "",
                                    "actionBy_Name": "Uli",
                                    "actionBy_Account": "uli26819",
                                    "action": "complete",
                                    "Comment": ""
                            }
                    ]
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Json.Net's implementation of JSONPath supports this concept.
However, you can still get the information you want if you break the query into two steps:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken stepId = obj.SelectToken("Item.State.stepId");
JToken actionDate = obj.SelectToken(string.Format("$..Step[?(@.stepId=='{0}')].actionDate", stepId));
Console.WriteLine(actionDate.ToString());
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KunYTf

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the answer. I thought about that, but hoped, that there would be a direct solution.

Comment: Well, Json.Net is [open source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) after all; you could always implement the feature yourself if you are feeling ambitious.